# javascript check if $_POST exist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I have this scenario:

- in my index.html a form with a textbox and a button with method POST and action another page named middlescan.html
- middlescan.html that in body onload event call a js function named checkpost
- The js function into midlescan.html that have to check if a $_post variable is set or is not blank, in positive case make something, otherwise return to index.html

My question is:
How is possible in javascript check if a $_POST call was made??

My situation now:

1. In my index.html:

   ```
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="middlescan.html">
   <p>
   <label for="oStxt"></label>
   </p>
   <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <td width="6%">&nbsp;</td>
   <td width="17%"><input type="text" name="oStxt" id="oStxt" /></td>
   <td width="77%"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Invia" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
   ```
2. In middlescan.html

   ```
   <body onload = ckpost()>
   ```

3.in js file

```
function ckpost() {

// only continue if we have a valid xmlHttp object
if (xmlHttp)
{
// try to connect to the server
try
{
  // initiate reading the async.txt file from the serve

  xmlHttp.open(“POST", "php/check.php", true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  // change cursor to "busy" hourglass icon


}
// display the error in case of failure
catch (e)
{
  alert("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString());
}
}
}
```

1. in my checkpost.php

   ```
   <?php
   $datat = array();

   if(!is_null($_POST['oStxt']) || $_POST['oStxt'] != "") {
   ```

   $datat[urlpost] = $_POST['oStxt'];

   ```
   } else {
   ```

   $datat[urlpost] = "nullo";

   ```
   }
   ```

   //Creo il file json 
   echo json_encode($datat);

   ```
   ?>
   ```

but response is ever "nullo"
What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only possible via AJAX. JavaScript is ***client-side*** scripting. `$_POST` is part of PHP which is ***server-side*** scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do the check in php or use some ajax call to some php script as javascript has no access to the backend scripting languages except through ajax calls.

you could do the following in php if you need specific js code to be execute based on some php variable

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['somevar']) && $_POST['somevar']=="Some Value") {
     echo <<<END
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           //do something here.
        });
     </script>
END;
  }
?>
```

OR have a js file loaded

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['somevar']) && $_POST['somevar']=="Some Value") {
     echo <<<END
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/someJSFile.js"></script>
END;
  }
?>
```

But note the javascript will not run till the browser has loaded the page and is not executing within php.

Comment: Thanks at all. My problem is that i have already an ajax call in my procedure. Before i had a single html page that onload event called an ajax function that with DOM and javascript generated at fly the new page. Now i have to split in 2 html pages the process, first with a form POST pass to the second page the textbox data and second page call ajax function anc dinamically build the page

Comment: @almal then have the script that,that ajax call makes output data letting you know the status of the post variable you need to know about. otherwise make yet another ajax call to do it, you can have more than one ajax call.

Comment: ok but in my second page i call a function like ckpost() and on this function on js file a made an xmlhttp call like xmlHttp.open("POST", "php/ckpost.php, true);?

Comment: @almal get the response within your `handleRequestStateChange` function

Comment: yes i check it with response11 = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); but the response is ever "nullo" because in php $_post is null. How i have to pass the value? From first html page to second? From second to js function?From jsfunction to ajax call?

Comment: you never save your $_post data from your post index.html to middlescan, put the data into something persistent like a session variable. then check the session variable in your chkpost.php file.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is server-side variable not accessible to javascript!

If you want to check variables to be `POST`ed in the form before sending:

```
<form action="some_url" onSubmit="if (this.input_name.value == ''|| this.input_name.value==' ') { alert('empty value found'); return false;}">
```

If you want to detect if Ajax call was made:

```
 $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
       alert('ajax was used!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can check every form elements if they are set or not on client side itself if it is about just to check if form elements are filled or empty.

Like:

```
if(document.getElementById("form_element1")) {
     alert('Value set');
}
```

Else, you got to create a bridge file in PHP, so you could call the that file via AJAX.